# How do I force youtube link to open in browser and not in app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I want users to view a youtube video, like in a popup, but the link redirects to youtube app,. I tried

```
myWidth = 350;
myHeight = 150;
var left = (screen.width - myWidth) / 2;
var top = (screen.width - myHeight) / 2;
var myURL = 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX';
var title = 'Song';
window.open(myURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + myWidth + ', height=' + myHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left,'_blank');
```

This works for desktop, but for mobile it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If there was no click, when you try to open the window, the browser will think that this is an obsessive advertisement and block the window.

Do the following: Handle click event to the button, and call your code there.